# HTML Video not working in safari

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have created a mp4 video and called it in the below html5 video tag as follows

```
<video width="100%" autoplay="" loop="">
<source src="http://beta.jointviews.com/testbytes/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/videos/testbytes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

the video works fine in mozilla and chrome but not in safari and mobile devices specially on androids and ipod,ipads{i could check only in these)

i have read in the **[link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp#table2)** that safari supports mp4 but it is not

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqaro0vr/

Comment: It's working fine in safari, may be your browser is not updated, please update.

Comment: my version is  5.1.7 and i am using windows

Comment: i have also 5.1.7, and it working fine please check screencastlink
http://screencast.com/t/7nDmFM8Q8h

Comment: it shows unavailable images